# How to dynamically bind the ItemSource of a ListView which has ItemTemplateSelector containing Multiple DataTemplates which have Different DataTypes?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, datatemplateselector, itemsource

I have an ItemTemplateSelector which contains Multiple DataTemplates which have Different DataTypes.
I thus have multiple ItemSources based on Module Selected.
How to bind my ListView with multiple ItemSources based on the module selected?

**Explanation:**

1)ViewModel_A is my ItemSource and DataTemplateA is my DataTemplate when my Module A is Selected

2)ViewModel_B is my ItemSource DataTemplateB is my DataTemplate when my Module B is Selected

I tried Implementing a BaseViewModel and tried binding the BaseViewModel Type in my ItemSource But this doesn't allow the access of derived class properties.

How to Dynamically Select My ItemSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1

First Create a `UserControl` which contains your `ListView` in your Xaml and two `DependancyProperty` for `ItemSource` and `DataTemplate`

**DataList.Xaml**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MultipleDataTemplate.DataList"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>

   <Grid>
   <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource,Mode=OneWay}"></ListView>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**DataList.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class DataList : UserControl
{
    public DataList()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    #region ItemsSource
    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set {  SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }              
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(object), typeof(DataList), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion
    #region ItemTemplate
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DataList), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion
}
```

### Step 2

Now you can you this usercontrol with any multiple DataTemplate's and multiple itemsource as below

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MultipleDataTemplate.Cars"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:controls="using:MultipleDataTemplate">
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CarKey" x:DataType="controls:Car">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind carprop1}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind carprop2}"></TextBlock>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BikeKey" x:DataType="controls:Bike">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Bikeprop1}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Bikeprop2}"></TextBlock>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>        
        <controls:DataList ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemSource,Mode=OneWay}" ItemTemplate="{x:Bind ItemTemplate}"></controls:DataList>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Cars" Click="CarsClick"/>
            <Button Content="Bike" Click="BikeClick"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class Cars : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public object _ItemSource { get; set; }

    public object ItemSource
    {
        get { return _ItemSource; }
        set
        {
            _ItemSource = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public DataTemplate _itemTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return _itemTemplate; }
        set
        {
            _itemTemplate = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public Cars()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void CarsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemSource = new List<Car>() { new Car() { carprop1 = "1", carprop2 = "2" } };
        ItemTemplate = this.Resources["CarKey"] as DataTemplate;
    }

    private void BikeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemSource = new List<Bike>() { new Bike() { Bikeprop1 = "1", Bikeprop2 = "2" } };
        ItemTemplate = this.Resources["BikeKey"] as DataTemplate;
    }
}
public class Car
{
    public string carprop1 { get; set; }
    public string carprop2 { get; set; }
}
public class Bike
{
    public string Bikeprop1 { get; set; }
    public string Bikeprop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can You Explain a bit more with an example of 2 item sources bro?

Comment: Sure i ll add it to the solution